# How do I delete all items from DynamoDB table using Boto3 library in Python when both partition key and sort key is given?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

'''
import boto3

```
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id ='xxxxxx',
    aws_secret_access_key ='xxxxx',
    aws_session_token ='xxxxx'
    )
dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb',region_name='us-east-2')
table = dynamodb.Table('table_name')
scan=None

with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    while scan is None or 'LastEvaluatedKey' in scan:
        if scan is not None and 'LastEvaluatedKey' in scan:
            scan= table.scan(
                ProjectionExpression='primary_key',
                ExclusiveStartKey=scan['LastEvaluatedKey']
            )
        else:
            scan = table.scan(ProjectionExpression='primary_key')

        for item in scan['Items']:
            batch.delete_item(Key= {'primary_key': item['primary_key'],'sort_key': item['sort_key']})

#  Here primary_key is the primary partition key and sort_key is the primary sort key

# Error :
# KeyError : 'sort_key'
```

'''

I am trying to delete all items from table(truncate) using boto3 library in Python.
I am getting KeyError issue although this key is present as primary sort key.

Comment: This error means the `item` dictionary doesn't have a key named `sort_key`. Double check the `item`.

Comment: Checked that twice.  I'm not sure if in ProjectionExpression too we need to pass the sort_key or anywhere else. Or is it just in delete.items that we pass sort_key.?

Comment: Can someone look on this please..

Comment: Oh, you need to add the `sort_key` to the ProjectionExpression as well.

Comment: Okk so will it be like this rit... 
 scan= table.scan(
                ProjectionExpression='primary_key', 'sort_key' ,
          ExclusiveStartKey=scan['LastEvaluatedKey']
            )